# Trivia Game not scoring correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function

So as I'm learning, I've been tasked with creating a Trivia Game. I really thought I was on the right track. The problem is, when I click "done" on my game, no matter the answers. They all come back incorrect. I'm not sure where the flaw is in my coding. If someone could point out the error that would be amazing.

```
$('#start').on('click', function(){
game.start();
})

$(document).on('click','#end',function(){
game.done();
})

var questions = [{
question:"The Fantastic Four have their headquarters in what building?",
answers:["Stark Tower","Fantastic Headquarters","Baxter Building","Xavier Insitute"],
correctAnswer:"Baxter Building",
}, {
question:"Peter Parker works as a photographer for?",
answers:["The Daily Planet","The Daily Bugle","New York Times","The Daily Rag"],
correctAnswer:"The Daily Bugle"
}, {
question:"S.H.I.E.L.D.'s highest ranking agent is?",
answers:["Nick Fury","Captain America","Natalia Romanova","Peter Parker"],
correctAnswer:"Nick Fury"
}, {
question:"What vehicle is the Avengers primary mode of transport?",
answers:["A bus","The Quinjet","The Blackbird","The Blackhawk"],
correctAnswer:"The Quinjet"
}, {
question:"Ghost Rider is also known as?",
answers:["The Guardian Devil","The Spirit of Hate","The Spirit of Vengeance","The Red Skull"],
correctAnswer:"The Spirit of Vengeance"
}];

var game = {
correct: 0,
incorrect: 0,
counter: 10,
countdown: function(){
    game.counter--;
    $('#counter').html(game.counter);
    if(game.counter<=0){
        console.log("Time is up!");
        game.done();
    }
},
start: function(){
        timer = setInterval(game.countdown,1000);
        $('#wra').prepend('<h2>Time Remaining: <span id ="counter">120</span> Seconds </h2')
        for (var i=0;i<questions.length;i++){
            $('#wrap').append('<h2>'+questions[i].question+'</h2');
            for(var j = 0; j<questions[i].answers.length;j++){
            $("#wrap").append("<input type = 'radio' name =  'question-" +i+"' value = '"+questions[i].answers[j]+" '> "+questions[i].answers[j])
        }
    }
    $('#wrap').append('<br><button id="end">DONE</button>')
},
done: function(){
    $.each($('input[name="question-0"]:checked'), function(){
        if($(this).val()===questions[0].correctAnswer){
            game.correct++;
        } else {
            game.incorrect++;
        }
    });

    $.each($('input[name="question-1"]:checked'), function(){
        if($(this).val()===questions[1].correctAnswer){
            game.correct++;
        } else {
            game.incorrect++;
        }
    });

    $.each($('input[name="question-2"]:checked'), function(){
        if($(this).val()===questions[2].correctAnswer){
            game.correct++;
        } else {
            game.incorrect++;
        }
    });

    $.each($('input[name="question-3"]:checked'), function(){
        if($(this).val()===questions[3].correctAnswer){
            game.correct++;
        } else {
            game.incorrect++;
        }
    });

    $.each($('input[name="question-4"]:checked'), function(){
        if($(this).val()===questions[4].correctAnswer){
            game.correct++;
        } else {
            game.incorrect++;
        }
    });

    this.result();
},

result: function(){
    clearInterval(timer);
    $('#wrap h2').remove();
    $('#wrap').html("<h2>All done!</h2>");
    $('#wrap').append("<h3>Correct Answers: " + this.correct + "</h3>");
    $('#wrap').append("<h3>Incorrect Answers: " + this.incorrect + "</h3>");
    $('#wrap').append("<h3>Unanswered Questions: " + (questions.length-(this.incorrect+this.correct)) + "</h3>");

}
```

}

Comment: One note: `$('#wra').prepend...`

Comment: `value = '"+questions[i].answers[j]+" '` <----

Comment: I would also recommend saving that jQuery object since you are reusing it a bunch.  `var $wrap = $('#wrap');` then you can do `$wrap.____` for whatever jQuery you have.

Comment: @epascarello I don't understand what you are say. Should I remove that? Or is the problem within that?

Comment: @nurdyguy that is a great tip! I'll be using that going forward with my studies

Comment: You do not see the extra space? So your attribute is `value="foo "` so `"foo" !== "foo "`

Comment: Yea I see that now. Thanks so much.

Comment: One last note:  Probably the most important thing in programming is learning how to debug.  In javascript that means opening the console (F12 for most windows browsers) and putting a stop in the code so you can see exactly what is happening.  Then you can compare `$(this).val()` with `questions[0].correctAnswer` and see exactly why they don't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in the line

```
   $("#wrap").append("<input type = 'radio' name =  'question-" +i+"' value = '"+questions[i].answers[j]+" '> "+questions[i].answers[j])
```

if you notice you append an extra "space" on each correct answer at `questions[i].answers[j]+" '`

So your values comparison between the correct answers and selected values is never true due to that extra space

Comment: THANKS! It's crazy how a single thing like that can mess it up. It solved my issue.